# Hide 3rd-level submenu on WordPress unless active

Tags: css, wordpress, class, menu, navigation

I'm building a simple custom theme with WordPress, where the menu is intended to be displayed in a sidebar as a list. By default only the complete menu including all sub-menus is being displayed:

- menu item 1

  - submenu 1
  - submenu 2

    - 3rd level submenu 1
    - 3rd level submenu 2 - **active**
    - 3rd level submenu 3
  - submenu 3
- menu item 2

  - submenu 1
  - submenu 2

    - 3rd level submenu 1
    - 3rd level submenu 2
    - 3rd level submenu 3
  - submenu 3
- menu item 3

  - submenu 1
  - submenu 2

    - 3rd level submenu 1
    - 3rd level submenu 2
    - 3rd level submenu 3
  - submenu 3

What I want to achieve is that only the 3rd level sub-menu is displayed which has the currently displayed page. Like this:

- menu item 1

  - submenu 1
  - submenu 2

    - 3rd level submenu 1
    - 3rd level submenu 2 - **active**
    - 3rd level submenu 3
  - submenu 3
- menu item 2
- menu item 3

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="menu-hauptmenue-container">
<ul id="menu-hauptmenue" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-87">
        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-203" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-203">
        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page2/">Page 2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-86">
        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page3/">Page 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-277">
                <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page3/2019-2/">Submenu 1st level 1</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-483" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-475 current_page_item menu-item-483">
                        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page3/2019-2/X/" aria-current="page">Submenu 2nd level 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-474" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-474">
                        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page3/2019-2/Y/">Submenu 2nd level 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-284" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-284">
                        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page3/2019-2/Z/">Submenu 2nd level 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-278">
                <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page3/2018-2/">Submenu 1st level 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-286" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-286">
                        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page3/2018-2/A/">Submenu 2nd level 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-285" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-285">
                        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page3/2018-2/B/">Submenu 2nd level 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88">
        <a href="https://www.testdomain.test/page4/">Page 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I figured out that with some CSS classes I can achieve to only show the currently active menu, but can't figure out how to show it's adjacent siblings...

```
li .menu-item-has-children {display: none;}

li .current-menu-item menu-item-has-children {display: list-item;}

li .current-menu-parent {display: list-item;}
```

I'd be grateful about any hints to a right combination of classes. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Its difficult to solve coding issues when we can't see the code :) Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us so we can help, and edit your question to include the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us what you've tried (we do don't suggest the same thing again) and what went wrong(so we know what to fix), so that we have the information we need to help you fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have now modified the question and hope it is more understandable.